# Repassar variavel via GET URL jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho o seguinte jQuery

```
$(".quantidade_lotes").change(function() {
    var quantidade_linhas = $("#quantidade_linhas").val();
    var quantidade_lotes = $(".quantidade_lotes").val();
    var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();

    var url = "php/lotes.php?linhas=" + quantidade_linhas + "&lotes=" + quantidade_lotes + "&mensagem=" + mensagem;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.lotes_lista').load(url);
    },3000);    
});
```

Tenho o campo mensagem: Ao digitar uma mensagem "teste", eu consigo recuperar e repassar ela para a url, normal e recuperar dentro do PHP via GET, mas, se eu digitar uma mensagem maior, que contenha espaços e etc, consigo apenas recuperar do campo, mas não consigo passar a mensagem na URL.

Como eu posso fazer para recuperar esta mensagem com espaços? pensei em transforma-la em HTML, ou alguma forma, para que eu possa repassar esta variável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu recomendaria que você utilizasse uma chamada ajax ao invés do load.

```
var quantidade_linhas = $("#quantidade_linhas").val();
var quantidade_lotes = $(".quantidade_lotes").val();
var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();

$.ajax({
  url: 'php/lotes.php',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {
    linhas: quantidade_linhas,
    lotes: quantidade_lotes,
    mensagem: mensagem
  },
})
.done(function(ret) {
  console.log("success");
  $('.lotes_lista').html(ret);
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
  console.log("complete");
});
```

E esse erro ocorre devido a codificação da url, que não aceita espaços.
Leia mais sobre isso aqui https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_cento

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado! :)